# Get surface light properties

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

If I shine a light on an object with OpenGL, is there a way to iterate through all of the polygons of my object and extract the intensity of light that is shining on them?

Comment: What do you need this for? You're calculating that information yourself, either in your application or through your shader.

Comment: I'm trying to build a physics model where I can accurately determine the pressure light is exerting on a surface of an object.  I can get the shadows and everything in a quick and simple way letting OpenGL do the math over the complex objects.  I'd like to extract from the shader the magnitude of the light on each polygon.  I think from there I can use that as a scaling factor against the light pressure computation and get a much more accurate magnitude of pressure than the normal flat plate type model yields.

Comment: I don't have the expertise to help you here, and as far as I know, there's no way to retrieve information from the pipeline. What I don't understand is, you should already be writing the lighting calculations yourself in the vertex or fragment shader; it's inefficient, but you can pull that out to the application, can't you?

Comment: one possibility: make 2 framebuffers, render the result of the lighting to the first, then render each face with a different color to the second, that way you can perform picking but instead of having the data from only 1 fbo , you get it from the already calculated lighting buffer.

Comment: @esel You are correct that I am doing the light calculations.  But when I set the light power and diffusion as out variables back in my main loop I get a single value.  I expect 100's of values from all of my surfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Transform feedback. Short version, you "draw" the scene but instead of the outputs from the vertex shader stage being rasterized, the attribute(s) you select are stored into buffer object(s) where you can retrieve them or re-use them in another pass.

Chapter 7 of the OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition has the full details.